# kubernetes nginx ingress subpath to subdomain redirection

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, guacamole

I am trying to achieve below proxy_pass settings, basically one of the services is listing to subdomain.example.com/guacamole but I want to serve it as subdomain.example.com

```
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://guacamole:8080/guacamole/;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_cookie_path /guacamole/ /;
    access_log off;
    # allow large uploads (default=1m)
    # 4096m = 4GByte
    client_max_body_size 4096m;
    }
```

Below is nginx ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: guacamole-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - subdomain.example.com
  rules:
  - host: subdomain.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /guacamole
        backend:
          serviceName: service-guacamole-frontend
          servicePort: 8080
```

I tried using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `path: /guacamole` with `path: /` should do the trick.

```yaml
  rules:
  - host: subdomain.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /  # replace `/guacamole` with `/`
        backend:
          serviceName: service-guacamole-frontend
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: This configuration is redirecting to subdomain.example.com/guacamole, not subdomain.example.com, which is the main moto.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `app-root` annotation.

From nginx-ingress [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite):

> If the Application Root is exposed in a different path and needs to be redirected, set the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root to redirect requests for /.

Try to use:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: guacamole-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /guacamole
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - subdomain.example.com
  rules:
  - host: subdomain.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service-guacamole-frontend
          servicePort: 8080
```

[Here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root) you can find another example.

Comment: This configuration is redirecting to subdomain.example.com/guacamole, not subdomain.example.com, which is the main moto.

Comment: @RahulSharma So please clarify what your trying to achieve.